# is there a clear explanation why Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync exception throws?

Tags: asp.net-core

Im trying to execute an async task to insert a new record to my database using command queries in asp.net core! and whenever my code tries to run this line

```
await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken);
```

it throws this exception

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

i have no idea what to do! i even spent a good time searching for a solution.

I hope you can help

and this is the full exception

> stackTrace: " at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.ReaderModificationCommandBatch.ExecuteAsync(IRelationalConnection
>   connection, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ↵ at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Update.Internal.BatchExecutor.ExecuteAsync(DbContext
>   _, ValueTuple2 parameters, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ↵   at   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.ExecuteAsync[TState,TResult](TState
>   state, Func4 operation, Func4 verifySucceeded, CancellationToken
>   cancellationToken) ↵   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(IReadOnlyList1
>   entriesToSave, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ↵ at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ↵ at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChangesAsync(Boolean
>   acceptAllChangesOnSuccess, CancellationToken cancellationToken) ↵ at
>   AN.RSM.Application.Employees.Commands.CreateCustomer.CreateEmployeeCommand.Handler.Handle(CreateEmployeeCommand
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
>   ~\Employees\Commands\CreateEmployee\CreateEmployeeCommand.cs:line 69 ↵
>   at
>   AN.RSM.Application.Infrastructure.RequestPerformanceBehaviour2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate1
>   next) in ~\RequestPerformanceBehaviour.cs:line 25 ↵ at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPostProcessorBehavior2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate1
>   next) ↵ at
>   MediatR.Pipeline.RequestPreProcessorBehavior2.Handle(TRequest
>   request, CancellationToken cancellationToken, RequestHandlerDelegate1
>   next) ↵ at
>   AN.RSM.WebApis.Areas.Employees.Controllers.EmployeesController.Create(CreateEmployeeCommand
>   command) in ~\Controllers\EmployeeController.cs:line 50 ↵ at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionMethodExecutor.TaskOfIActionResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper
>   mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[]
>   arguments) ↵ at System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result() ↵ at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>   ↵ at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()
>   ↵ at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext
>   context) ↵ at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State&
>   next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted) ↵ at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
>   ↵ at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()"

Comment: what do the exception details say?

Comment: i will post the full exception below

Comment: Could you show your code?Is it possible that you have incorrect ConcurrencyStamp?Refer to https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9166